# Only allowing one instance of a class member in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am creating a helper class in front of the google map API - just for the sake of learning.

I'd like to keep only one instance of the google.maps.Map object around in my class, even if someone decides to instantiate another instance of the class.

I'm coming from a .NET background, and the concept is simple there - however I'm still getting acclimated to javascript (and ES6), so any pointers are much appreciated.

Here's a snippet sort of explaining (through comments) what I'm going for.

```js
class Foo {
    constructor(bar) {
        // If someone else decides to create a new instance
        //  of 'Foo', then 'this.bar' should not set itself again.
        // I realize an instanced constructor is not correct.
        // In C#, I'd solve this by creating a static class, making
        //  'bar' a static property on the class.
        this.bar = bar;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not set a flag? `if (flag) return; /* early */ flag = true;`. You might also want to consider never exposing the constructor globally.

Comment: A rough equivalent to a C++ class static in Javascript is to store something as a property on the constructor.  In Javascript, functions are objects so they can have properties too.  In your example, you could use `Foo.bar`.

Comment: Consider wrapping the constructor in an IIFE that returns just one instance. It can't be called again.

Comment: Are going to *need* multiple instances of `Foo`, with different states? If no, then **don't use a `class` for it**. Create a "module" using a simple object literal.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi - you're absolutely correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```js
var instance = null;

class Foo {
  constructor(bar) {
    if (instance) {
      throw new Error('Foo already has an instance!!!');
    }
    instance = this;

    this.bar = bar;
  }
}
```

or

```
class Foo {
  constructor(bar) {
    if (Foo._instance) {
      throw new Error('Foo already has an instance!!!');
    }
    Foo._instance = this;

    this.bar = bar;
  }
}
```

Comment: Until someone resets *Foo._instance*…

Comment: Well, someone shouldn't do it as it's a private property (well, "pseudo" private). But, good point. Updated the answer.

Comment: If the OP is worried about "someone" creating a second instance, then "someone" can do lots of things… ;-)