# Javascript Class - return previously constructed instance in constructor

Tags: javascript, class, singleton

I googled "javsascrpit only allow one instance of class" and found [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33335872/only-allowing-one-instance-of-a-class-member-in-javascript), but it's not quite what I wanted. It's close though:

```
class Foo {
  constructor(bar) {
    if (Foo._instance) {
      throw new Error('Foo already has an instance!!!');
    }
    Foo._instance = this;

    this.bar = bar;
  }
}
```

What I actually wanted was, the first time you call `x = new Foo()` it obviously would do the constructor and return you the class instance, but the second time you call it, `y = new Foo()`, it would return you the same instance already created, so that `y === x` would be true.

I was thinking something like this:

```
class Foo {
  constructor(bar) {
    if (Foo._instance) {
      this = Foo._instance;
      return;
    }
    Foo._instance = this;
    this.bar = bar;
  }
}
```

However, I wasn't sure if this pattern is valid, would work, or if there are better patterns.

Comment: So, what question is then actually left to ask?

Answer (score 0):

all I had to do was test it a bit in Chrome Snippets to find my answer:

```
class Foo {
  constructor(bar) {
    if (Foo._instance) {
      return Foo._instance;
    }
    Foo._instance = this;
    this.bar = bar;
  }
}

x = new Foo('x');
zz = new Foo('zz');
console.log(zz.bar); // you'll find this is x
console.log(zz === x)' // this should be true
```

apparently you can't have this = something, but you can return something else in a constructor.